# How can I run linux cp -r with variables command from python code

Tags: linux, python-3.x, shell

I would like to run cp -r $src $dest from python code.
The issue raises when I try to pass src and dest as variables and not as strings.

What is the easiest way to copy a directory and all subfolders with the files to a new directory?

I've tried:

```
src='src/dir'
dest='dest/dir/
import os
myCmd = 'cp -R '+src+' '+dest
os.system(myCmd)
```

I also tried to use subprocess:

```
subprocess.run(myCmd, shell=True)
```

or:

```
subprocess.run('cp -r "$s" "$d"', shell=True, env={'s': src, 'd':dest} )
```

It worked only when I specify the src and dest as strings:

```
subprocess.run('cp -r src/dir dest/dir', shell=True )
```

Comment: You're missing a quote in `dest='dest/dir/` (at the end)

Comment: Can you try it again with `subprocess.run('set -x; cp -r "$s" "$d"', shell=True, env={'s': src, 'd':dest} )`? This will not fix the problem, but it will output debugging info that will help determine what the problem is. Please edit your post and copy-paste the complete output exactly (do not redact or abbreviate the output, because this will hide problems with encoding and quoting). There should be one line starting with `+ cp` and at least one other starting with `cp: `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a system-level call, use [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) :

```
import shutil
source_folder = '/somewhere/some_folder'
dest_folder = '/elsewhere/some_folder'
shutil.copytree(source_folder, dest_folder)
```

This will work on every platform